# Как исправить эффект рисования с использованием scroll?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, qpainter

При перемещении скролла, круги рисуются не по центру.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QApplication, QLabel, 
QHBoxLayout, QScrollArea
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor, QMouseEvent, QImage, QPixmap, 
QPalette
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint
class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.flag = False
        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):
        self.resize(500, 500)
        self.image = QImage(self.width(), self.height(), 
        QImage.Format_ARGB32)
        self.image.fill(QColor(255, 255, 255))
        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
        scroll = QScrollArea()
        self.valueWidth = scroll.verticalScrollBar().value()
        scroll.setBackgroundRole(QPalette.Dark)
        self.label.setGeometry(10, 10, 500, 500)
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(self.image))
        scroll.setWidget(self.label)
        self.hbox.addWidget(scroll)
        self.setLayout(self.hbox)
        self.show()

    def mousePressEvent(self, e):
        if e.button() != Qt.LeftButton:
            self.flag = False
        if e.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.flag = True
            self.paint = QPainter(self.image)
            self.ellips(e)
    def paintEvent(self, e):
        paint = QPainter(self)
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(self.image))
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        if self.flag:
            print(e.pos())
            self.ellips(e)
    def ellips(self,e):
        self.paint.setBrush(QColor('yellow'))
        self.paint.drawEllipse(e.pos() - QPoint(10, 10), 20, 20)

        self.update()
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = Example()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Код в вопросе невалидный, исправьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: @gil9red исправил

Comment: Рекомендации: 1) делайте отступы между методами, в вашем месиве сложно разбираться 2) изменение размера и положения окна выносите за его конструктор 3) группируйте код по смыслу или объекту, например имеет смысл все действия с label делать подряд, а не размазывать по конструктору

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что отслеживали позицию курсора на виджете, а рисовали на его ребенке, а из-за того что ребенок находился на scrollArea, то могла быть видима только его часть.

[В этом примере я переписал код](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/0b5805d6f2b5cf575286f32d0758e679c6766e0d/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/draw_image_label__on_scroll_area), чтобы движение мышки отслеживалось непосредственно на ребенке:

```
import sys
import traceback

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QLabel,  QHBoxLayout, QScrollArea, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor, QPixmap, QPalette
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QEvent


def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))

    print(text)
    QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Error', text)
    sys.exit()


sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.flag = False

        self.image = QPixmap('image.jpg')

        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.label.setPixmap(self.image)

        # Установка фильтра событий
        self.label.installEventFilter(self)

        self.scroll_area = QScrollArea()
        self.scroll_area.setBackgroundRole(QPalette.Dark)
        self.scroll_area.setWidget(self.label)

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.scroll_area)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        # Рисовать будем на картинке
        self.painter = QPainter(self.image)
        self.painter.setBrush(QColor('yellow'))

    def eventFilter(self, obj, e):
        # Если событие пришло от self.label
        if obj == self.label:
            # Если событие нажатия кнопки мышки и зажата левая кнопка
            if e.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress and e.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
                self.flag = True
                self.draw_ellipse(e)

            # Если событие отпускания кнопки мышки и зажата левая кнопка
            elif e.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonRelease and e.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
                self.flag = False

            # Если событие движения мышки и зажата левая кнопка
            elif e.type() == QEvent.MouseMove and self.flag:
                self.draw_ellipse(e)

        # Стандартная обработка событий
        return super().eventFilter(obj, e)

    def draw_ellipse(self, e):
        self.painter.drawEllipse(e.pos(), 20, 20)
        self.label.setPixmap(self.image)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    w = Example()
    w.resize(500, 500)
    w.show()

    app.exec()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]